# how do i make android studio load the new manually downloaded gradle version (8.3) whenever i make a new project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i had some issues with the previously installed version of gradle that was automatically downloaded inside android studio, so i removed it and downloaded the newest gradle version manually. the problem is that everytime i create a new android studio project, it tries to download the old version of gradle that had issues instead of using the manual version i downloaded. i have to go to settings and manually sync the gradle version that i downloaded everytime i make a new project.

going into  File--> Settings--> Build, Execution, Deployment--> Build Tools--> Gradle  and changing the gradle source from 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file to the specified location only changes it for that single project. when i make a new project it changes to the 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file again.
i tried changing the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties but that doesnt work either, and the file resets when i create a new project.